# How to filter out the null values in X-axis for Bar chart in Spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I am working with a data set where I have few columns with few null values in those. When I try to plot bar chart with these columns on x-aixs it is showing separate bar with this having no name.
Is there any way we don't show the null values in the columns as Bars.

[image]

Please look into the image attached, I don't need to show the first bar with no name on X-Axis.

Comment: How your question is related to c# and ironpython? Have you tried filtering on the column in the x axis excluding blanks?

Comment: Hi Mate, In spotfire we can include iron python and C# to Customize Visualizations

Comment: if you are interested only in solutions with coding and not with manual selection, then please specify that in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to TWAndrews' suggestion you can also filter in the appropriate graph by going Right Click > Properties > Data > Limit Data using Expression: [Column name] Is Not Null

Answer (score 0):

Filters, which are tied to columns both in the GUI and API, include an option to exclude empty values. Select the appropriate value for your use case.